# Add new record to linq query result

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query as follows:

```
var paymentInfo = 
    from i in dbconnect.tblPayments
    where i.tenderId == _tenderId
    select i;
```

This query has some results, but I need to add an additional result that I already have, from the variable PaymentInfo.

For example suppose that my query has 2 results i need to add another result to "PaymentInfo" using linq.

I thought that the result is a kind of list, and that I could call .Add(PaymentInfo), but this doesn't work

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Concat` to concat another sequence to the end of this one.

```
var paymentInfo = paymentInfo.Concat(someOtherPayments);
```

Comment: i have more that one record

Comment: @user3216600 Then concat all of the records, not just one.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that the result is a kind of list

No, the result is an `IEnumerable<T>` which is read-only.  You can *create* a list by calling `.ToList()` and *then* add an item to it.

```
var paymentInfo = (from i in dbconnect.tblPayments 
                  where i.tenderId == _tenderId 
                  select i).ToList();

paymentInfo.Add(existingPayment);
```